# How to get ceil value in Duration

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I have `Duration` object which I want to return full duration in days (rounded up), so for:

1. 1m - 1d
2. 1d - 1d
3. 1d1h - 2d
4. 1d1m - 2d

Unfortunately `toDays()` method is returning only full days. Is there any method for getting ceil value?

Comment: "floor" -> "ceil", yes?

Comment: Yeah, ofc ceil...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you can do a `ceil` with integer division is to add 1 less than the denominator:

```
(numerator + denominator - 1) / denominator
```

So, do the same here: add 1 nanosecond less than 1 day to your duration, and then use `toDays()`.

```
duration.plusDays(1).minusNanos(1).toDays()
```

Looking [in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toDays--), it suggests that `toDays()` might only consider to second precision. However, [this little demo](https://ideone.com/2i9HTV) shows that it works to nanosecond precision (at least for non-negative durations).